# Xamarin.Forms.Maps iOS Padding

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble finding a solution for my problem. I am looking to set the padding for the Xamarin Forms Map (Mapkit/MKMapView) on iOS (Custom Renderer).

For Android it can be set in the custom renderer with  NativeMap.SetPadding(10,200,10,10) but I cannot find a way to do it in iOS.

The problem I am trying to solve is that the compass on the map appears on the top right corner of the map (iOS) and since I do have my own controls on the top of the map, the compass is not accessible.

On android setting the padding pushes the compass down below my controls and solves the issue.

I’d appreciate any suggestion on how to solve it for iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### MapKit.MKMapView

You can create your own MKCompassButton and alter its X/Y position (via its Frame) on the map.

```
var compass = MKCompassButton.FromMapView(mkMapViewInstance);
compass.CompassVisibility = MKFeatureVisibility.Visible;
compass.Frame = new CGRect( new CGPoint(25,25), compass.Frame.Size);
```

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcompassbutton?language=objc

#### Google.Maps.MapView (iOS)

> You can add padding around the edges of the map using the GMSMapView.padding property. The map will continue to fill the entire container, but text and control positioning, map gestures, and camera movements will behave as if it has been placed in a smaller space. This results in the following changes:

```
myGMSMapViewInstace.Padding = new UIEdgeInsets(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using GoogleMaps on iOS but Mapkit. I updated my original post as this detail was not mentioned. Thanks anyway

Comment: @OliverMartins Ahh...ok, MKMapView does allow you to define custom insets to determine where the map is positioned with the view, but the UI controls, i.e. the compass, does not move within thus insets. You can control the compass location via making your own `MKCompassButton` (iOS 11+) and thus position it within its owning UIView via the Frame origin(x/y), see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this solution. It works as I needed it! I added the following to make it work and hide the original compass: mapView.AddSubview(compass);
                nativeMap.ShowsCompass = false;